# breaking references to a form C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have a license project (Database Interaction Project) and I want to remove all references from a form that loads data from a DB, because I load a lot of data and the memory usage is high. I profiled the application (.Net Memory Profiler, Ants) and got the references that are connected to that form:

`Module1.cs / Class1 -> Module2.cs / Class2 with the reference ref 1 written on the arrow`

I must remove them without drastic changes, and the program should still work :). If I put the references to null the program crashes because it might need those refs again The trouble is, I think, that the reference showed can be declared in different modules than the ones showed by the Profiler, making it harder to follow.

In the Data.cs i have the `Data` class and in it I declare

```
mVController = table.Resolve<ImVController>();
```

`mVController`  -    is of Type `ImVController` (doesn't matter the name)
`table`     -    is of type `IUnityController`
`ImVController` -     is the interface where `mVController` is declared
`Resolve`       - makes container of the same type with mVController

I want to know if i put `mVController = null` when no longer needed  will the GC enter / object will be eligible for collection?

or the `table` will have hold the reference to the object of type `ImVController`? My guess it that it will be eligible.

what if some object is declared:

`object newObject = DomainObjectFactory.GetObject(typeOfObject);`

then it uses mVController:

`(newObject as Class1).MethodFromClass1(mVController.Property1, mVController.Property2, ...);`

do I get rid of the reference like this:

`object = null;` then it will be collected at a certain time?

another question: should the references be passed with ref in a method (e.g. `public void method(ref Type obj)`
then make obj = null; in the method so that the object is null also? Will all refs from all the project point to null> so the GC  could collect? 
 and then call the method also with ref: `method (ref obj)` when the object is no longer needed and should go out of scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> if i put mVController = null when no longer needed will the GC enter / object will be eligible for collection?

Depends on IUnityController implementation: if it owns ImVController, there will be no profit resetting mVController. Anyway, GC will not collect garbage until your app will lack of memory.

> make obj = null; in the method so that the object is null also

If your object is referenced with other variables/objects, GC will not collect it. If not, you object will be collected. Some time.

Comment: so what is the best practice for breaking a reference to an object?